# 301 Redirect WITHOUT subdirectories/query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, vhosts

I've been searching for this for hours now. Everything I find does the exact opposite.

I want to 301 redirect ALL traffic from an old domain to a new one. I DON'T want anything to pass across to the new domain, just redirect to the domain itself and nothing else.

I would prefer to do it in a vhost, but htaccess is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old domain vhost config (or .htaccess):

```
RewriteRule .* http://newdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```